# nativescript localize can't switching languages

Tags: javascript, mobile, plugins, nativescript

I need some help.
I'm coding mobile app on nativescript and I use nativescript-localize for multi-language function.
Question is 
- I try to set default by add in file name ( ex. finish.default.json ) but on app, it show on english language (I have en and fi lang in my app), So how to fix this? 
- How to switching language function?

I use this plugin >> https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localize

or anyone have some good plugin for internationalization plugin, you can tell me :)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Default language is something that will be picked up when your app doesn't support device's current language.

Since your app supports French and English, system will pickup English only when device's language is English. If device language is set to something else, let's say Spanish, then it will pickup French as your app doesn't support Spanish and French is default.

Answer (score 0):

Language is changed by changing the language of the device. Use the Settings app for this (outside of your application). A user will typically not expect to change language within an app and instead want a seamless experience that just adheres to the language they are already using on the device.

**Other notes**
This plugin requires your filenames to match the locale ISO codes. For Finnish (two n’s), the file should be called `fi.json`.

When using the `.default.` infix, you are specifying which language should be applied if the user’s language is not available.